# Java Plugin is invisible for all browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, java

Currently I can't run JAVA applets on any of my browsers (Chrome, FF, IE). JAVA is installed on my computer ("java" command displays the runtime options). The about:plugin pages do not display the JAVA plug in at all.

I think this can be related to the fact that I installed JAVA in D disk - could this be the case? If so how do I tell Chrome/FF where too check for the plug in?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you use?

Comment: I use Windows 7 x64

Comment: Did you install Java 32bit, or Java 64bit? 

This matters as most browsers are 32-bit software, so they need the 32-bit java installed so they can use it.

Comment: @Darius Gr8 suggestion. After updating my FF to nightly x64 I'm finally able to run JAVA applets!. Please consider writing it as an answer so I can accept it!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install Java 32bit, or Java 64bit? This matters as most browsers are 32-bit software, so they need the 32-bit java installed so they can use it.

As the OP stated, there are 2 ways around it:
Use a 64-bit Browser (if available), and use 64-bit Java
or
since Browsers are usually still 32-bit, install 32-bit Java (you can have both 32-bit and 64-bit java)